# frida cannot create instance of class com.android.okhttp.Request$Builder with android 11

Tags: httprequest, frida

I want to create a simple **http request** with **frida** while hooking the function. With **android 6, everything is ok**, but when I try with **android 11, there's a big prolem** here:

```
Error: no supported overloads
at U (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:484)
at value (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:800)
at get (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:696)
at get (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:681)
at <anonymous> (/inject.js:52)
at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/vm.js:16)
at perform (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:193)
at make_custom_request (/inject.js:55)
at onEnter (/inject.js:42)
```

Here is the code:

```
var req = _uri + param;
Java.perform(function(){
    var OkHttpClient =  Java.use("com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient");
    var Builder = Java.use("com.android.okhttp.Request$Builder").$new();     //error here
    var request = Builder.url(Java.use("java.lang.String").$new(req)).build();
    OkHttpClient.$new().newCall(request).execute();
});
```

I'm new with frida. Help me please.

**Update**
I know this issue due to *restriction on non-sdk interface* mechanic in android 9+.
So, how can i bypass this mechanic with frida?

Comment: Are you sure the app is the same of Android 6 and 11? Are you sure the requested class really exists in the app you have hooked with Frida? Extract it from device and decompile it e.g. using Jadx or apktool to see if the class you want to hook really exist. The class you requested only exists in pretty old OkHTTP versions, may be the app uses a newer version?

Comment: I use the same app for both of android version.  I'm definitely sure that it has class "com.android.okhttp.Request$Builder".

Comment: Is the Android 11 device a real physical one or an emulator?

Comment: I use real physical device. Another things, when I getMethods(), It does't show all functions of class "com.android.okhttp.Request$Builder" in android 11, but android 6 does.

Comment: I also just had the case that certain classes are not visible to Frida but they are in the app (On an Android 9 and 11 device). It seems like those platforms no longer load all classes on start-up. Instead some classes are loaded later may be on-demand when a certain activity or service is started? At least I noticed that the classes I miss are accessible after opening a certain activity that makes use of them.