# How to disable ssl pinning in android app using Objection

Tags: android, okhttp, frida, man-in-the-middle, sslpinning

I have a simple app and am trying to bypass its ssl pinning with no luck. Already did `android sslpinning disable` but didnt work.

Based on this article https://blog.nviso.eu/2020/11/19/proxying-android-app-traffic-common-issues-checklist/ I then used `apktool` to decompile my app then searched across all smali classes for anything that might be doing pinning using `grep -ri "java/lang/String;\[Ljava/lang/String;)L" smali` There was 3 smali files and I found the okhttp3 stuff in the last smali file `smali_classes3`.

This was the output:

```
smali_classes3/okhttp3/CertificatePinner$Builder.smali:        "(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)Lokhttp3/CertificatePinner$Builder;",
smali_classes3/okhttp3/CertificatePinner$Builder.smali:.method public final varargs add(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)Lokhttp3/CertificatePinner$Builder;
```

So I created this script `hook2.js`

```
Java.perform(function(){
    var Pinner = Java.use("okhttp3.CertificatePinner$Builder");
    Pinner.Builder.overload('java.lang.String', '[Ljava.lang.String;').implementation = function(Builder, b)
    {
        console.log("Disabling pin for " + Builder);
        return this;
    }
});
```

and tried to inject it using objection:

`objection explore --startup-script hook2.js`

I get an error

```
Importing and running startup script at: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='hook2.js' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
[{'type': 'error', 'description': "TypeError: cannot read property 'overload' of undefined", 'stack': "TypeError: cannot read property 'overload' of undefined\n    at <anonymous> (/script2.js:3)\n    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/vm.js:11)\n    at _performPendingVmOps (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:238)\n    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:213)\n    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/vm.js:11)\n    at _performPendingVmOpsWhenReady (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:232)\n    at perform (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:192)\n    at <eval> (/script2.js:8)", 'fileName': '/script2.js', 'lineNumber': 3, 'columnNumber': 1}]
```

How can I get this injected properly or is my script wrong?

Comment: For an unknown reason some apps do no longer load all classes right at the beginning and thus Frida can not hook them. I am not sure if this is is caused by Android itself or a bug in Frida. Please see the very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70135333/150978

Comment: @Robert Oh thats a bugger. Is my script correct though? Any way around this or injecting  at some point after starting? Im still new to this so struggling with a few things